# How to add two numpy arrays together?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

Having a little trouble on something that seems pretty simple. I want to join these two arrays to meet output:

```
array([['category_1', '4500', '5000'], ['category_2', '3200', '5000'], ['category_3', '3000', '5000'], ['category_4', '2000', '5000']], dtype='<U8')
```

I have some data

```
data = np.array([['category_1', '4500', '5000'], ['category_2', '3200', '5000']])
```

And I have this other data

```
other_data = np.array([['category_3', '3000', '5000'], ['category_4', '2000', '5000'])
```

And I get this error when I do this

```
np.concatenate(data, other_data)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Try `np.concatenate((data, other_data))`. `concatenate` takes a tuple input.

Comment: Oh wow that works! But why? A tuple is defined without parenthesis though. At least that's what I think. I can put a = 1, 2 and output will be a tuple

Comment: Because that's the way NumPy has defined its function: check [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: In `np.concatenate(a, b)`, `a,b` is tuple, but it is unpacked into the arguments of the function.  `a` corresponds to the `(a1,a2...)` argument of the function signature, ant `b` is taken to be the `axis` argument (that's why it complains about a `scalar index`).  `concatenate` does not use a `*args` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = np.array([['category_1', '4500', '5000'], ['category_2', '3200', '5000']])
other_data = np.array([['category_3', '3000', '5000'], ['category_4', '2000', '5000']])
np.concatenate((data, other_data), axis=0)
```

Comment: what does axis do? I got the same output without it.

Comment: axis generally defines, whether you want to add vertically(column) or horizontally(row),